# Passing image src to backing bean in Seam

Tags: java, jsf, seam, pixastic

I am new to SEAM and JSF and using pixastic for clientside image manipulation, I have successfully got crop rotate and some other operations working today. While doing image operations I found one interesting fact that whenever I do particular operation Eg: CROP the image, the src attribute of img tag I am using gets changed. Also, if we copy this "src" value and put it in new HTML and open that HTML we get modified image.

Using this technique I want to access src of image using jquery ".attr()" function and pass that value to backing bean in SEAM for save, is this possible?

Thanks in advance,
Rahul

Comment: Probably... have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it works pretty well. Problem is internet explorer where pixastic  doesn't work.

Comment: So... what is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: @RahulBorkar - You should probably post your solution as an answer and accept it, so that others can benefit from the common knowledge.